# Charts in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts

I want a sample chart in `mvc`. I tried the below code in my controller. It's directly returning the chart as `filestreamresult`. The chart is not being displayed in my view. I want to display this `chart` in my `view`. How can I display it in view?

```
public ActionResult Chart1()
{
    Chart chart = new Chart();

    chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());

    chart.Series.Add(new Series("Data"));

    chart.Legends.Add(new Legend("Stores"));
    chart.Series["Data"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
    chart.Series["Data"].Points.AddXY(1.0, 5.0);
    chart.Series["Data"].Points.AddXY(2.0, 9.0);

    var returnStream = new MemoryStream();
    chart.ImageType = ChartImageType.Png;
    chart.SaveImage(returnStream);
    returnStream.Position = 0;
    return new FileStreamResult(returnStream, "image/png");
}
```

my view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
<img src='/MyChart/Chart1' /> 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in you view page (cshtml or aspx) add a image src to your action

```
<image src='controllername/chart1' />
```

Comment: added it but the controller is not returing view, its returnning chart image